# Does all stream controllers should be closed or not in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, stream

in the following link you'll see streams are not closed and ignored with "// ignore: close_sinks" dart analysis option and I wonder why is that?

https://github.com/a14n/dart-google-maps/blob/master/lib/src/generated/google_maps_core.js.g.dart

this is its package link
https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps